# Can't seem to validate for true, only false?

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a simple check to see if a user is signed in or not. Heres the function that does this for me:

```
function checkAuth() {
    var IsSignedIn = false;
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            global: false,
            dataType:"json",
            url: '/utility/SignInStatus',
            success: function(result) {
               IsSignedIn = (result);
               console.log(IsSignedIn); // shows true
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("you're not logged in");
            }
        });
        console.log(IsSignedIn); // shows true when logged in, false when not.
}
```

It asks the server for a response if the user is logged in. The server only provides a response if the user is logged in. The response is a boolean value of `true`. If the user is NOT logged in, then nothing is returned from the server which means the `error` part of the $.ajax call runs and the `IsSignedIn` variable remains `false` as default.

In another jQuery file, I want to deal with the result of this checkAuth() function:

```
$(document).on('click','a', function(event) {
 if (!checkAuth()) { 
    return; // the alert from the error part of checkAuth() shows
}
 else {
    alert("yes you're logged in!"); // this never runs even if the user is logged in
}
});
```

How come it never manages to get to the `else { }` part even though `checkAuth()` is returning true?

Comment: You may need to return true in the checkAuth function. `return true;` or return false when failed `return false;`

Comment: `success: {return true}, error: {return false}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to return true in the checkAuth function. `return true;` or return false when failed `return false;`

Example:

```
function checkAuth() {
var IsSignedIn = false;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        global: false,
        dataType:"json",
        url: '/utility/SignInStatus',
        success: function(result) {
           IsSignedIn = (result);
           console.log(IsSignedIn);
           return true; // return true if logged in
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("you're not logged in");
            return false; // return false if not logged in
        }
    });
    console.log(IsSignedIn);
}
```

Comment: Nope, its not working. It returns true that the user is logged in, but in the $(document).on('click') event handler never displays the alert saying "`alert("yes you're logged in");`"

Comment: @volumeone That is odd. Do you see if it is loading the AJAX after it returns?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. I've got Firebug open and the console is showing "true" when the user is logged in. But nothing more happens.

Comment: I used the `if (checkAuth() == 'false')` instead of `if (!checkAuth())` and I now get all the alerts in one go. So first I get "yes you're logged in" even though I'm not logged in. Then I get you're not logged in. And then finally Firefox says prevent further dialogs appearing. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: @volumeone have you tried doing `console.log(checkAuth())` before the if statement to see what it is outputting.

Comment: I have finally managed to make it work. It wasn't even a conversion issue. It was the console.log debugs that were making it go crazy. Thank you for your help Joshua.

Answer (score 1):

Probaly a conversion error from server code to javascript.
Try something like this :

```
if (checkAuth() == "false")
{}
```

Debug your code to see how your checkAuth is interpreted in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are *Asynchronous* (the first A) and therefore the result is not available immediately. And, setting `async` to `false` is not recommended as it freezes the page until there's a response from the server. You have to re-write your code such that rather than waiting for a `true/false` from a function in order to take an action, you take an action when the Ajax call completes and returns a result:

```
$(document).on('click','a', function(event) {
    var IsSignedIn = false;
    $.ajax({
        global: false,
        dataType:"json",
        url: '/utility/SignInStatus',
        success: function(result) {
           IsSignedIn = (result);
           console.log(IsSignedIn);
           console.log(IsSignedIn); //<<<<<====== put your checks here!!
           if (!IsSignedIn) { 
               alert( 'not logged in' );
           } else {
               alert("yes you're logged in"); 
           }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("you're not logged in");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In this case it is set to async: false, so (although not a god idea), this method will freeze all until AJAX response is available. Anyway the methods (error and success) should return something to make this work...

Comment: Good point! Thanks. Async: false is actually not recommended. I have removed that setting.

Comment: This has completely changed the code. I need checkAuth() as a seperate function that can be called from multiple other places. Its going to be used to see if a user is logged in or not and possibly display a modal dialog to ask them to register.